# ARM Assembly Tutorials / Resources / Tips

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, processor

I'm struggling to learn ARM Assembly and would like some resources to help. I am experienced in a couple of languages such as C, Javascript and other minor languages.

I'm trying to learn IOS exploitation with the help of understanding the ARM Assembly language. If anyone has any resources, tutorials, videos, books, files that helped them learn, i would very much appreciate it if you could pm or comment it below.

It would also be much appreciated if anyone who is experienced with ARM Assembly, to provide a guide or any useful tips into helping the beginners such as myself.

Anything will be helpful and generous! Thanks very much.

Comment: The ARM tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arm/info has a few links.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) is also relevant; looking at compiler output for simple functions is a good way to start.  Any more than that is off topic: asking for links to tutorials and guides is off-topic for an SO question.  See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an answer for your question but a good starting point for me for learning iOS security was cycript. : http://www.cycript.org/

And hopperapp. https://www.hopperapp.com/

With those tools I rarely had to decode assembly language.

Comment: Are you experienced in IOS exploitation and reverse engineering?

Comment: That's not my field of expertise but something I like to toy with